Tileset created iregular
I want to create a game but when I download asset I discovered that I don't know how to change lines that they will not overlap. I know I can just edit and create a big space between, but I would like to know if there is simpler option. For some reason head of one sprite is higher than legs of others. I like to keep everything in tilesets
I tried to change offset but it didnt work

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
